# Rotating Content in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

Is there a way to add Rotating Content, whose contents change every few seconds, to an Orchard CMS website?

By Rotating Content, I mean that I want to display some Content which disappears after an amount of time (say 5 seconds) and gets replaced by another piece of Content, drawn either at random or in sequence from a list of Content Items. A bit like a slide show, but with Content including text with nice fonts, html links, images, etc... rather than just images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a projection and then style it with a jquery slider plugin to do it. You will have a lot of control over what is displayed that way. Steve Taylor wrote a nice tutorial on one way to achieve this (by creating a custom new layout): http://www.stevetaylor.me.uk/image-carousel-using-twitter-bootstrap-and-orchard-cms-projections

Or you can checkout the Featured Item module on the gallery: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.FeaturedItemSlider I think you create featured items that are displayed in the slider.

There is another module a colleague of mine has made which he will be releasing to the gallery that does a similar thing to the featureditemslider module but uses projections. So look out for that one very soon.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: *It is more like Steve Taylor's example Harry (i dropped the extensions for featured item slider as projections are more flexible). See it running here - its the main carousel http://breakoutdeveloper.com/ - package on skydrive http://sdrv.ms/17iLqKc 
It uses a projection so potentially anything can go into it.  
Just create an alternate for the content being displayed in the carousel. Add its filter if only a few content items in the group need displaying. Let me know if it needs any more work. The content display type in there is just a specialized summary alternate.